# What SqlDbType maps to varChar(max)?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

What SqlDbType maps to varChar(max)? SqlDbType.VarChar says that it is limited to 8K, though that may be a documentation error.

Comment: Currently I see 3 different answers, which solution  did you actually use?

Comment: In the end I found that not explicitly setting the SqlDbType was the best way to go. It is far less error prone and doesn't have to be changed when the stored proc is changed.

Comment: But now your code is building an execution plan every time a different length string is passed to the SP. It's not optimal. MSDN shows to use -1, as eglasius states below.

Comment: Good point, but still not worth the pain.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually you can use it with VarChar. If it is a parameter you can build it with: new SqlParameter("@myparam", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1)

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399384.aspx

Comment: Do I have to pass a size of -1 or can I just leave it blank?

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973260/what-size-do-you-use-for-varcharmax-in-your-parameter-declaration

Answer (score 0):

OK... Finally figured this out... if you get an error stating : "
    String[0]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0."
You merely have to set the size parameter of the output SQL Parameter as so:

```
Dim parameter As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@FinalImportCount", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
parameter.Size = 4000
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter)
```

Hope this helps someone -- been trying to figure this out for 2 hours.... grrrrr.

Answer (score -1):

Use VarChar, and set size to 2147483647 (2gb-1)