# What size do you use for varchar(MAX) in your parameter declaration?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I normally set my column size when creating a parameter in ADO.NET.

But what size do I use if the column is of type `VARCHAR(MAX)`?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@blah", SqlDbType.VarChar, ?????).Value = blah;
```

Answer (score 341, accepted):

In this case you use -1.

Comment: is there any performance drawback to setting all parameter lengths to -1, so I dont have to maintain a db-matching list?

Comment: Varchar(max) is treated identically to varchar(8000) for values less than 8000 bytes. For larger values the field is treated as a "text" field (aka a "CLOB"). This can affect query plan optimization and the efficiency of retrieving rows with larger values in this column, as the data is stored "out-of-row" requiring an extra lookup.

Comment: Use nvarchar(max) in sql and define length -1 with SqlDbType.NVarchar  in c#

Comment: If it wasn't for the answer by Sam Meshesha below - I would have missed your answer.  Your answer might get more votes if you put a sample line of code formatted as code.

Answer (score 72):

For those of us who did not see -1 by Michal Chaniewski, the complete line of code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@blah",SqlDbType.VarChar,-1).Value = "some large text";
```

Answer (score 6):

The maximum SqlDbType.VarChar size is 2147483647.

If you would use a generic **oledb connection** instead of sql, I found [here](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=97#11) there is also a LongVarChar datatype. Its max size is 2147483647.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@blah", OleDbType.LongVarChar, -1).Value = "very big string";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do something like this:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@blah",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "some large text";
```

size will be taken from "some large text".Length

This can be problematic when it's an output parameter, you get back no more characters then you put as input.

Comment: I seem to be getting an exception for an `SqlParameter` whose size I do not set, even though I do assign a value - however, I am not using that overload of `Add`, but create the `SqlParameter` instance myself. Does the overload of `Add` you are using already initialize `Size` to something maybe?

Comment: This is bad because it breaks the query plan optimizations. Having the same parameter with different sizes makes impossible to reuse the cached informations for the same query text forcing Sql Server to recalculate the execution plan. see also the comments on the Igor Macedo's answer

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass the size parameter, just declare `Varchar` already understands that it is MAX like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@blah",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "some large text";
```

Comment: This can have negative effects on your SQL server due to how the Execution Plan is calculated.

Comment: I found this not to be the case when using an output parameter. It result in the following error ` Exception:String[2]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.`  To fix this, use Size = -1 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087950/how-to-create-nvarcharmax-sqlparameter-in-c

Comment: As I have found out today this is actually bad as SQL server then has to recompile the plan each time. In our case it had 60,000 plans cached for a simple INSERT as we did not know this.