# How to save Spanish and Arabic characters in SQL Server 2008 R2 from a C# Windows application?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How to save Spanish and Arabic characters in SQL Server 2008 R2 from a C# Windows application?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your code?

Comment: If you have chosen a database access technology such as ADO.NET, LINQ-to-SQL, or Entity Framework, please indicate that. Then, the answers can be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server, use the [**`nvarchar()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) data type instead of `varchar()` to support unicode.

In your application, specify the parameter as `SqlDbType.NVarChar` as shown here: [How to create NVarchar(max) Sqlparameter in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21088034/2333499)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, use nvarchar()data type instead of varchar()to support Unicode.