# Different language in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on a C# project. I have created a dataset by use of sql server and I tried to show the data in DataGridView table. Then I added a button to change the selected data. when I use English language for editing the data, it works perfectly. But when I change the language, question mark is shown.

to edit the data I use the following commands.

```
sqlStr = "Update Employee Set FirstName = '" + FirstName.Text + "' Where ID = '" + ID.Text + "'";
        cmd.CommandText = sqlStr;
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

any help is appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your data is in Unicode? Do you use Windows Forms DataGridView?

Comment: yes, I use the persian language and Windows Forms DataGridView.

Comment: does Sql server set on the Persian codepage? it may be that the data can't be converted to Unicode

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: if you check the Sql server properties it has a codepage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support , also you can chack if database type is `nvarchar` which corresponds to Unicode data

Comment: I used nvarchar to define the type of variables in sql server as string. the point is that the DataGridView show the predefined data in persian perfectly but when I want to chage/edit the selected data it shows the ? mark

Comment: could you try to use Sql Parameters instead of string concatenation in the query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create NVarchar(max) Sqlparameter in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087950/how-to-create-nvarcharmax-sqlparameter-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
sqlStr = "Update Employee Set FirstName = '" + FirstName.Text + "' Where ID = '" + ID.Text + "'";
```

to:

```
sqlStr = "Update Employee Set FirstName = N'" + FirstName.Text + "' Where ID = N'" + ID.Text + "'";
```

*Without the `N` at the start, you are using `varchar` rather than `nvarchar`. Which basically means that Persian characters will show as ?*

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use SqlParameters like this:

```
sqlStr = "Update Employee Set FirstName = @FirstName Where ID = @Id";

SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@FirstName";
param.Value         = FirstName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@Id";
param.Value         = ID.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

This, also, avoid sql injection.