# Only first letter of particular data is getting saved in database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET MVC so bear with me here.

I'm creating a Registration page using ASP.NET MVC 5 with SQL Server; whenever I fire my create action method, it only stores only the first letter of my data like if I enter "Stack" it will only store 'S'.

I'm posting my controller code here. Please help and thanks in advance.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateUser()
{
    return View(db.ClsUsers.Create());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUser(FormCollection form, ClsUserReg userReg)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CoupanCodeManagmentContext"].ConnectionString))
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_UserReg_Ins ", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = userReg.Id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = userReg.Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mobile", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = userReg.Mobile;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = userReg.Email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = userReg.UserName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = userReg.Password;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ConfirmedPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = userReg.ConfirmedPassword;

        try
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Close();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("UsersList");
    }
}
```

[This is how it's getting saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQWgd.png)

Comment: Use [the constructor for `SqlParameter` that also takes the size of the parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameter__ctor_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_System_Int32_) and give the correct for the column size to it.

Comment: @PhongNguyen except for id every other filed is nvarchar(max) both in table and in stored procedure

Comment: @AnkitTiwari use -1 as size. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087950/how-to-create-nvarcharmax-sqlparameter-in-c

Comment: @JesúsLópez tried but nothing changed

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You didn't show the stored procedure, but I strongly suspect your **parameters** are defined as just `NVARCHAR` - without any length. In that case, the **default length** of this parameter is **exactly ONE character** - and the solution is simple: ***ALWAYS*** define an explicit **length** for your `NVARCHAR` parameters and variables in SQL Server! (also applies to `VARCHAR`, `CHAR` and `NCHAR`)

Comment: @marc_s actually it was just that, i forgot to add length in stored procedure after nvarchar and it caused massive headache, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the couple of things

- Mention the SqlParameter size manually by checking the columns size in SQL Server
- You need to specify the size for NVARCHAR parameters in the stored procedure.  If an nvarchar parameter does not have a size, it defaults to 1 character and will truncate the data that is passed to it.  [Refer more here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-stored-procedure-with-nvarcha)

**For example**

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UserReg_Ins]
    (    
       @Name nvarchar(500) = null,
       @Mobile nvarchar(500) = null,
       @Email nvarchar(500) = null,
       @UserName nvarchar(500) = null,
       @Password nvarchar(500) = null,
       @ConfirmPassword nvarchar(500) = null
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    --INSERT Statement
    END
```

Comment: that's it , this was the case i was not specifying any limit to nvarchar in stored procedure . Thanku somuch.