# How to set SqlParameter with varchar max size

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

would someone help me how to set the parameter with varchar(max) in .net
thanks in advance

There is my code:

```
Dim param As SqlParameter = Nothing

        Select Case strParameter
        Case "@item"
                param = New SqlParameter(strParameter, SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
            Case "@value"
                param = New SqlParameter(strParameter, SqlDbType.VarChar,  max)
        End Select
        param.Value = objDBHandlers.getValue(objValue)
```

Comment: Pass `-1` as the size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What size do you use for varchar(MAX) in your parameter declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973260/what-size-do-you-use-for-varcharmax-in-your-parameter-declaration)