# How to store a long string in a varchar(MAX) column by C# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, varchar

All related subjects I saw in this site discuss stored procedures and alike. I have a C# program that receives a string (not important from where, maybe file or uploaded) and tries to insert it into a `varchar(MAX)` column. My code is like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pxslt", mer.XsltTemplate);
```

It raised an error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

I changed it to:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@pxslt", SqlDbType.).Value = mer.XsltTemplate;
```

but still it raises the same error.

What is the solution? The size of my string is about 8100 characters.

Comment: Check the size of the column in the DB, likely this question is a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591473/error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-when-trying-to-insert

Comment: Your code is incorrect... `SqlDbType.VarChar` and assign a maximum value parameter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973260/what-size-do-you-use-for-varcharmax-in-your-parameter-declaration

Comment: Even if the column really is varchar(MAX), the stored procedure parameter might be declared incorrectly so make sure you check that too.

Comment: @itsme86 I dont use stored procedure.

Comment: Maybe post your SQL command.

Comment: SqlCommand command =
                    new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBMERCHANT(MERCHANTID,MERCHANTNAME,MERCHANTURI,DESCRIPTION,USERNAME,PASSWORD,LOGO,XSLTTEMPLATE)" +
                                    "values(@pid,@pnom,@puri,@pdes,@puser,@ppass,@plogo,@pxslt)");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", mer.merid);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pnom", mer.mername);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@puri", mer.uri);

Comment: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdes", mer.description);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@puser", mer.username);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ppass", mer.password);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plogo", mer.logo);
            command.Parameters.Add("@pxslt", SqlDbType.VarChar,-1).Value = mer.XsltTemplate;

            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

Comment: How do you know it is the parameter `@pxslt` that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this syntax:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@pxslt", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = mer.XsltTemplate;
```

NB: -1 equates to (MAX).

Comment: I tested this but still the same problem. I also tested this: command.Parameters.Add("@pxslt", SqlDbType.VarChar,mer.XsltTemplate.Length).Value = mer.XsltTemplate;

Comment: What data type is .XsltTemplate?  String I presume?
Can you also give us the definition for the stored procedure?  At least from the CREATE PROCEDURE down to the AS clause please?

Comment: I dont use stored procedure. As a hint, I use an mdf file as the database. Is it possible that this causes the problem?

Comment: Ah okay, assumed you were using SQL Server on account of the [sql] [server] tags.  If you are using MS Access I guess you will be constructing an INSERT statement rather than an EXECUTE statement, which is what the command.Parameters are normally for.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The error raises because of another field. This was a field varchar(15) and the program tries to insert a string of 20 chars. I also noticed that varchar(max) works even without casting to DbType.

Comment: Glad you found a solution :-)