# How to add SQL parameter with MAX value in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

When adding to a parameter collection in .NET C# using `SqlParamaterCollection.Add`, [an overloaded method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x(v=vs.110).aspx) determines the size of the parameter.

[Another overloaded method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s(v=vs.110).aspx) does not include the size of the parameter, but the example of its use shows the size being set immediately after the method is used.

In both cases, the documentation doesn't specify how to max the parameter size a "MAX" value. For example, as when inserting into a column of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

How should this be done?

```
// ? below indicates confusion on how to make this MAX.
// it only takes type "int"
var parameter = new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, ?);
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Comment: Interesting question, but why would you need to supply `MAX`? Why wouldn't you get the string's length and use it?

Comment: If direction is not output you don't need to set size.

Comment: You use -1. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087950/how-to-create-nvarcharmax-sqlparameter-in-c) and [Another Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973260/what-size-do-you-use-for-varcharmax-in-your-parameter-declaration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` without specifying the size, which is default to MAX, but should not exceed 8000 for `VARCHAR` and 4000 for `NVARCHAR`

Comment: can you provide documentation for those limits? i don't remember seeing that.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: that is the limits in SQL server, try to use `REPLICATE` to insert any string larger than that size, it will throw you the error

Comment: Actually, MAX indicates the column data is stored out of row while a number (up to 8000 for VARCHAR and 4000 for NVARCHAR) would be stored in row. This is more important for defining table structures than stored procedures. But MAX actually means 2 GB of data could be returned (at least for VARCHAR - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).