# OdbcParameter error - size of 0 for varchar(MAX) output parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc

I'm using:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64)
>   Dec 28 2012 20:23:12
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation   Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

I have a stored procedure which has a `varchar(MAX)` output parameter.

I'm calling it via an `OdbcCommand` and I've created a `VarChar` output parameter and added it to the `OdbcCommand` `Parameters` list:

```
new OdbcParameter("@MaxField", OdbcType.VarChar)
    { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, Size = -1 })
```

While debugging I can see that the `Size` field on the parameter is still -1 but when I run the query using `OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=String[2]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.
>   Source=System.Data
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter.GetParameterSize(Object value, Int32 offset, Int32 ordinal)
>          at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter.PrepareForBind(OdbcCommand command, Int16 ordinal, Int32& parameterBufferSize)
>          at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameterCollection.CalcParameterBufferSize(OdbcCommand
>   command)
>          at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments,
>   SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
>          at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
>          at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

I tried using the `OdbcCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(odbcCommand);` to examine the parameter information derived from the stored procedure and it said that the parameter had a Size of **2147483647** - however, if I try and use that value I get a different exception telling me

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException was unhandled
>   ErrorCode=-2146232009
>   HResult=-2146232009
>   Message=ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQLServer Driver][SQL Server]Invalid parameter 2 (''):  Data type 0x23 is
>   a deprecated large object, or LOB, but is marked as output parameter. 
>   Deprecated types are not supported as output parameters.  Use current
>   large object types instead.   Source=SQLSRV32.DLL   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
>          at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments,
>   SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
>          at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
>          at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

How should I configure my OdbcCommand output parameter to receive this output from the stored procedure?

This is on an existing, in-production database so trying to change the datatype of the field is sadly the absolute last resort. The field that is being selected is `varchar(max)`.

Edit: If the actual answer is "You just can't" then that would be acceptable - at least I would know for sure.

Comment: You need to use a reasonable size for your output parameter. 2147483647 is too large. What value do you expect your stored procedure to return?

Comment: The field is defined as `varchar(max)` - it will be able to hold any value that fits. The value of 2147483647 comes **from the OdbcCommandBuilder**.

Comment: @RacilHilan This question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973260/what-size-do-you-use-for-varcharmax-in-your-parameter-declaration - has the accepted answer stating **-1** is the `size` to use for `varchar(max)` but that is on an input parameter. I'm trying to work out how to get a `varchar(max)` output parameter working.

Comment: I understand, but that's a terrible design even if you get it to work. Check what value is returned and use a reasonable size accordingly.

Comment: @RacilHilan Let me put it this way - in a varchar(max) field, how large do **you** think it would be?

Comment: If you read the message that you posted in your question carefully, it clearly says: *"Deprecated types are not supported as output parameters"*, so the other question used it as input parameter, but you cannot use it as output. Both cases are terrible design.

Comment: No, let me put it in another way. I don't care how big `varchar(max)` is, it shouldn't be used as parameter (neither input nor output). Use a reasonable size like 250.

Comment: @RacilHilan thanks for the comments, but it's not getting me any closer to a solution. As I said, this is on an existing, in-production database so trying to change the datatype of the field is sadly the absolute last resort. And I can tell you now that the data is going be bigger than 250.

Comment: The 250 was just an example. Use another value if you like. What solution do you wan, it is telling you clearly that you cannot use it for output parameter, so what solution do you want if you refuse to fix the broken stored procedure? I understand your situation and you may have limited control over the existing db, but I don't see how that can be fixed in another way. You can use the maximum acceptable (non-deprecated) value if you like, does that work for you?

Comment: @MattJones - Just curious: Given that you are working in C#, is there a particular reason why you are using `System.Data.Odbc` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`?

Comment: @GordThompson I'm extending some existing code that is currently written using the `Odbc` classes - if this turns out to be a complete non-starter then I will definitely look into the `SqlClient` as an alternative.

Comment: @RacilHilan saying that a `varchar(MAX)` output parameter is just not going to be possible is an acceptable answer. The purpose of this question is to find that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with `System.Data.Odbc` then the following workaround might suffice. For the stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[HodorSpeaks] 
    @repeat int = 1, 
    @response varchar(max) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @whatHeSaid varchar(max);
    SET @whatHeSaid = 'HODOR! ';
    SELECT @response = REPLICATE(@whatHeSaid, @repeat);
END
```

the C# code

```cs
using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = 
        "SET NOCOUNT ON; " +
        "DECLARE @out varchar(max); " +
        "EXEC dbo.HodorSpeaks @repeat=?, @response=@out OUTPUT; " +
        "SELECT @out;";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OdbcType.Int).Value = 10000;
    string resp = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("{0} characters were returned", resp.Length);

}
```

tells me that

```
70000 characters were returned
```

Comment: Very interesting, and nicely sneaky. But I think I am going to have to accept that trying to get this to work "elegantly" is a forlorn hope.

Comment: Nice trick to avoid declaring an output parameter. Inelegant, but simple and works. +1

Answer (score 1):

`varchar(max)` was introduced in SQL Server 2005 to replace the `text` type. When the value is less than 8000, it is stored on page like a standard `varchar(n)`, while values above 8000 are stored off page like `text`.

The use of `text` or `varcha(max)` as a parameter is not recommended, and as the message is telling you, it is even not supported for output parameters:

> Data type 0x23 is a deprecated large object, or LOB, but is marked as output parameter. Deprecated types are not supported as output parameters. Use current large object types instead.

The best solution is to fix the stored procedure and change the output parameter from `varchar(max)` to `varchar(n)`. Otherwise, you can use `varchar(8000)` in your code for the parameter and hope that the stored procedure will never return a value more than 8000. The value 8000 is the maximum for the `varchar(n)` type.

Also, you may get around it by using a different (older) version of the ODBC driver that doesn't complain about the use of `varchar(max)` as an output paramter, but that obviously is not the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer based on your comments - in an ideal world I would prefer to rewrite the underlying database completely!

Comment: Yes, it is often better to rewrite badly coded applications, but sadly we're not in an ideal world and sometimes we have to live with what we've got, so I understand your situation.